# Autofac.Hangfire doesn't find registered types

Tags: c#, asp.net, autofac

I'm trying to use Autofac for DI in my ASP.NET MVC application. It works fine but I cannot solve a problem with Hangfire.

Here my startup.cs code:

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseSqlServerStorage("MyContext");

        var container = new AutofacContainer().Container;
        var resolver = new AutofacDependencyResolver(container);

        app.UseAutofacMiddleware(container);
        app.MapSignalR(new HubConfiguration
        {
            Resolver = resolver
        });

        AddSignalRInjection(container, resolver);
        app.UseHangfireDashboard();
        app.UseHangfireServer();
    }

    private void AddSignalRInjection(IContainer container, IDependencyResolver resolver)
    {
        var updater = new ContainerBuilder();

        updater.RegisterInstance(resolver.Resolve<IConnectionManager>());
        updater.RegisterInstance(resolver.Resolve<IMyContext>());
        updater.RegisterInstance(resolver.Resolve<ILiveData>());
        updater.RegisterInstance(resolver.Resolve<IErp>());
        updater.Update(container);
    }
}
```

}

here the AutofacContainer.cs:

```
public class AutofacContainer
{
    public IContainer Container { get; set; }
    public AutofacContainer()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        builder.RegisterControllers(typeof(MvcApplication).Assembly);
        builder.RegisterHubs(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()).PropertiesAutowired();
        builder.RegisterType<LiveData>().As<ILiveData>().PropertiesAutowired().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
        builder.RegisterType<MyContext>().As<IMyContext>().PropertiesAutowired();
        builder.RegisterType<Erp>().As<IErp>().PropertiesAutowired();
        Container = builder.Build();
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseAutofacActivator(Container);
        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new Autofac.Integration.Mvc.AutofacDependencyResolver(Container));
    }
}
```

here an extract from Erp.cs:

```
public interface IErp
{
    void InitializeMachines();
}

public class Erp : IErp
{
    public IConnectionManager ConnectionManager { get; set; }
    public IMyContext _context { get; set; }
    public ILiveData _liveData { get; set; }

    public Erp(IMyContext context, ILiveData liveData)
    {
        _context = context;
        _liveData = liveData;
    }

    public void InitializeMachines()
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

I add a job in this way:

```
Hangfire.BackgroundJob.Enqueue<Erp>(x => x.InitializeMachines());
```

I get the following Hangfire error:

```
Failed
An exception occurred during processing of a background job.
Autofac.Core.Registration.ComponentNotRegisteredException

The requested service 'MyProject.Classes.Erp' has not been registered. To avoid this exception, either register a component to provide the service, check for service registration using IsRegistered(), or use the ResolveOptional() method to resolve an optional dependency.
```

The message says the Erp service is not registered, but I don't understand why. As you saw above, I actually registered it:

```
builder.RegisterType<Erp>().As<IErp>().PropertiesAutowired();
```

Is the message saying something different I don't understand?

Comment: What happens if you remove `.As<IErp>()`? Or if you replace it with `.AsImplementedInterfaces().AsSelf()`?

Comment: Using the concrete type works! But all say to use interfaces in the real world...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is most likely your use of this line:

```
Hangfire.BackgroundJob.Enqueue<Erp>(x => x.InitializeMachines());
```

You have told Hangfire to enqueue a job using the concrete type `Erp`.

*Unfortunately*, you didn't tell Autofac how to resolve an `Erp`. You told it how to resolve an `IErp`:

```
builder.RegisterType<Erp>().As<IErp>().PropertiesAutowired();
```

You thus should change the second code sample to remove `.As<IErp>()`.